# How can I get a Future<MyObject> without using ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading

I would really like to do something like this:

```
 Callable<MyObject> myCallable = ....
 Future<MyObject> = new Thread( myCallable).start();
```

I basically want to start a single long-running task that runs in parallel with my main task, and I do not want pooling or thread re-use. The Executors stuff seems to be very pooling oriented and it requires me to shut down the pool, all of which I don't want to do.

I *want* to use the "Callable/Future" pattern because I may later have to introduce Executors, but as things currently stand they're just overhead.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try FutureTask.  It doesn't have any explicit dependency on the Executor framework and can be instantiated as is, or you can extend it to customize it.

Answer (score 15):

Well, you can fairly easily write a helper method:

```
public static Future<T> createFuture(Callable<T> callable)
{
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<T> ret = service.submit(callable);
    // Let the thread die when the callable has finished
    service.shutdown();
    return ret;
}
```

EDIT: To expand on [alphazero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839440/how-can-i-get-a-futuremyobject-without-using-executorservice/839467#839467), you'd use `FutureTask` like this:

```
FutureTask<MyObject> future = new FutureTask<MyObject>(myCallable);
new Thread(future).start(); // FutureTask implements Runnable
// Now use the future however you want
```

And yes, I'd say this is nicer than my first answer :)

Comment: it is ok for ExecutorService frequently instantiated and shutdown many times? Aren't it to be reused?

Comment: @AwanBiru: The question is about a single long-running task, which is why I've given this answer. I suspect it's *okay* but not ideal to create lots of `ExecutorServices`, but you'd be best off asking a new question with your actual context - especially as this question/answer is 10 years old, and there may be new approaches. (I haven't worked with Java professionally for a while.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. As ur suggestion,..I will.

Answer (score 0):

The callable/future stuff is based around thread pooling. If you need to do the same operation many times, I would strongly recommend using a pool.

If you do not want to use a thread pool, then I would suggest using a thread manually. It is not hard to do what you want by using a single thread and joining on it.

```
class X extends Thread {
   MyObject result;

   public void run() {
      // .. do the operation here. Set result
   }

   public MyObject getResult() {
      // This will block until the thread is complete
      join();
      return result;
   }
}
```

To run this call:

```
X x = new X();
x.start();
```

eventually you will call getResult which will block until X's thread is complete:

```
x.getResult();
```